# how to install , configure and manage dns using powershell on Windows server 2008?

Tags: powershell

Salam every body 
I need help to learn how
 to Install,Configure and Manage dns using only powershell on Windows 2008?

Comment: When you say *dns* in *Install, Configure and Manage dns* -- Do you mean the `DNS Server Role`?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

## Installing `DNS Server Role` via Powershell

Open an elevated Powershell window and enter the following commands.

1. `Import-Module Servermanager`
2. `Add-WindowsFeature 'DNS' -restart`

For a more general guide about installing server roles via powershell, take a look at this page:  [Adding Server Roles and Features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732263.aspx#BKMK_powershell)

On that page, just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `Powershell`.

## Configuring `DNS Server Role` via Powershell

Since configuration is a very general topic, here's the link to the documentation:

[Domain Name System (DNS) Server Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649850.aspx)

You can list all the available commands with `Get-Command –Module DnsServer`

Comment: I guess the correct cmdlet is Add-WindowsFeature 'DNS' -restart

Comment: @FredJand I just checked; you're right!  I've updated my answer accordingly.